# Java jdbc2 MysqlDataSource connected but cannot send queries

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, datasource

I'm using my own class to keep a persistent connection from the jdbc MysqlDataSource class (see code below). However after working fine for about a day it stopped working. Connections are still being made, however queries are not coming through. Furthermore the connection seems to be in SLEEP mode while I am sending new queries.  Besides the time variable in my SHOW PROCESSES keeps going up, indicating queries are not getting through.

What could be my problem here?

```
private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
private final MysqlDataSource source = new MysqlDataSource();
private Connection connection;

public MysqlStore(String name, String server, int port, String user, String password) {
    source.setDatabaseName(name);
    source.setServerName(server);
    source.setPort(port);
    source.setUser(user);
    source.setPassword(password);
}

private Connection getConnection() {
    try {
        if (connection == null || !connection.isValid(1)) {
            connection = source.getConnection();
        }
        return connection;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public CompletableFuture<QueryResult> runQuery(String sqlText, Object... arguments) {
    CompletableFuture<QueryResult> resultFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
    executor.submit(() -> {
        Connection connection = getConnection();
        try {
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlText);
            for (int i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                statement.setObject(i + 1, arguments[i]);
            }
            resultFuture.complete(new QueryResult(statement));
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            resultFuture.completeExceptionally(e);
        }
    });
    return resultFuture;
}

public CompletableFuture<Integer> runUpdate(String sqlText, Object... arguments) {
    CompletableFuture<Integer> resultFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
    executor.submit(() -> {
        Connection connection = getConnection();
        try {
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlText);
            for (int i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                statement.setObject(i + 1, arguments[i]);
            }
            resultFuture.complete(statement.executeUpdate());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            resultFuture.completeExceptionally(e);
        }
    });
    return resultFuture;
}

public CompletableFuture<Integer> runUpdateGetKey(String sqlText, Object... arguments) {
    CompletableFuture<Integer> resultFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
    executor.submit(() -> {
        Connection connection = getConnection();
        try {
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlText, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            for (int i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                statement.setObject(i + 1, arguments[i]);
            }
            statement.executeUpdate();

            try (ResultSet res = statement.getGeneratedKeys()) {
                if (res.next()) {
                    resultFuture.complete(res.getInt(1));
                } else {
                    resultFuture.completeExceptionally(new IllegalStateException("Expected a generated key but found nothing."));
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            resultFuture.completeExceptionally(e);
        }
    });
    return resultFuture;
}

@Override
public void close() {
    try {
        executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (!executor.isTerminated()) {
        executor.shutdownNow();
    }
    try {
        if (connection != null && !connection.isClosed()) {
            connection.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public class QueryResult implements Closeable {
    PreparedStatement statement;
    ResultSet result;

    public QueryResult(PreparedStatement statement) {
        this.statement = statement;

        try {
            result = statement.executeQuery();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public ResultSet get() {
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        try {
            if (result != null) {
                result.close();
            }

            if (statement != null) {
                statement.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the parent class of MysqlStore? Where are you overriding close() method from in MysqlStore? How can you be sure that close() method is being called at all?

Comment: @SergioMontoro The parent class is [Closable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html). Close method is called on the termination of the program. But the problem is not that it won't close, since when terminated connections are dropped. But while 'connected' nothing comes back. (The queries are actually executed but not returned it seems..)

Comment: If the queries start but not stop it is probably because the table is blocked by another transaction. How do you ensure that QueryResult.close() is always called before MysqlStore.close()? May it be that you are closing the connection before the resultset and the statement?

Comment: QueryResults are enclosed in the new try ( ) { blocks, ensuring #close() is called when the resultset is finished being used. But since the query is not returning this will currently not happen, so closing the MysqlStore will indeed close before the resultset is closed. Is there a way to check whether any table is being blocked? And can I get rid of this block somehow?

Comment: Execute SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS and search for “WAITING FOR LOCK”, “HOLDS THE LOCKS" and "LOCK WAIT"

Comment: It seems like operations ARE getting through, just not get send back to my client. Can there be something that's stopping mysql from sending it's results back to the client? The logs also show queries and their results just fine.
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
0 read views open inside InnoDB
Main thread process no. 6873, id 120174461921024, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 3, updated 0, deleted 0, read 28657
0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.00 reads/s
`